# How to get data to my view that comes from more than one object?

Tags: model-view-controller

So I have read some of the similar asked questions, but I don't know if the right questions were asked.  It appears there are different ways to get data from multiple entities passed into your View Model, but I want to go about it the correct way.

I basically have 2 entities available in my controller, and I need to pass different information from both entities to my view.  I have read about creating a SomeNameViewModel class that would be instantiated in my controller ViewResult method.  With the SomeNameViewModel object assigning the data into a single object to pass to the View Model

Example:

```
public ViewResult List()
{
  var vm = new SomeNameViewModel {
    products = _prodRepo.All();
    catName =  <Some Expression>;
return View(vm);
}
```

But is this the best practice way to go about this?

I am using Nhibernate:  So would this be better handled in my Fluent Mapping so that I have access to the other entity through the one-to-one mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a model per view is a common (and good) way to go about providing data to your views.  View models can encompass values from more than one entity type and may contain ancillary data as well.  You might want to also consider using view-specific models for any entities contained in your view model to further isolate your view from your domain objects.  This way you can provide to your view exactly the data they need and no more and, if your domain model changes, you may be able to only modify how the view-specific model gets updated from the domain model rather than propagating the change throughout your views.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I have tried combing the internet for literature on a "view specific" model and am coming up dry (matter of fact one of the few finds was another comment of yours).  Can you point me to some information on this model.  I sounds from your explanation that it might be a model that encapsulates other models, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Also - is it typical practice to have lambda's in your View?  For example, If I have a foreign key relation ship between my tables, when I am iterating through my Model, and displaying each (i.e. Product), and I need to list the Category.name property based on the Product.CategoryId field, I would assume I could use a lambda (is that correct)?

Comment: @pghtech - all I mean is that you don't directly use your domain model in the view.  you create a separate model, typically one per view, that contains the data for that view.  this model might contain data from more than one domain model or type of domain model.

Comment: @pghtech - you'll need to be careful that your related entities are loaded at the same time.  If they are delay-loaded, the data context/repository may not be available any longer.  Typically, you'll want to make sure that if you're using LINQ that you materialize the query (using ToList() or enumerating it) before you pass the data off to the view.  I don't have a problem using some code in a view, though I'd be careful of using anything other than that required to construct the display.